# JConsole MBeans tab does not have "com.sun.management" node in left tree

Tags: jmx, jconsole

My Environment is JBoss 5.1 (Jdk 1.5.x) on Windown 7

I have started JConsole from JDK 1.6 bin folder, it picked up the local running above JBoss app. To take heap dump as mentioned in [jconsole docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html), but, in the MBeans tab, I am not seeing "com.sun.management" node in the tree.

I have mentioned the following JAVA_OPTS in the jboss run bat file:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1234
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Comment: You are able to connect to the process and see other beans?  Just not `com.sun.management`?

Comment: I can see 4 nodes (JMImplementation, java.lang, java.util.logging and jboss.ws) but not "com.sun.management".

Comment: I wonder if it is restricted because of access limitations.

Comment: Both are running in the same machine(local box). I do not know jconsole has any access limitations?

Comment: It could be about internal JVM security permissions.  It may be the Jboss section of the code does not have the permissions to access the sun beans.